# Java @extension in hudson - when and why

Tags: java, hudson, clearcase

What is the case when we need to use `@extension` in java for hudson?
By definition it says, `for a class/method so that hudson can locate implementation of ExtensionPoints automatically.`

What are extension points in hudson? An example may give a better picture of theory.

Comment: Could you link to the doc which states that about extension? That may help to know how this is related to ClearCase.

Comment: It is used in the clearcase plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ItemListenerImpl.java

Comment: Ok, and where the sentence "for a class/method so that..." comes from?

Comment: I checked with eclipse, but here is the link of class: http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/Extension.html

Comment: Ok, that matches what I found below. I will have to dig a bit more.

Comment: what to import to use this annotation? because I'm having this error  : unable to find class for annotation
   @Extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see what the JAvaDoc says for:

- [`hudson-core/3.0.1/hudson/Extension.java#Extension`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.hudson/hudson-core/3.0.1/hudson/Extension.java#Extension)

> Marks a field, a method, or a class for automatic discovery, so that Hudson can locate implementations of [ExtensionPoints](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.hudson/hudson-core/3.0.1/hudson/ExtensionPoint.java#ExtensionPoint) automatically.
>
> (In contrast, in earlier Hudson, the registration was manual.)
>
> In a simplest case, put this on your class, and Hudson will create an instance of it and register it to the appropriate ExtensionList.
>
> If you'd like Hudson to call a factory method instead of a constructor, put this annotation on your static factory method. Hudson will invoke it and if the method returns a non-null instance, it'll be registered. The return type of the method is used to determine which `ExtensionList` will get the instance. Finally, you can put this annotation on a static field if the field contains a reference to an instance that you'd like to register.
>
> This is the default way of having your implementations auto-registered to Hudson, but Hudson also supports arbitrary DI containers for hosting your implementations. See `ExtensionFinder` for more details.

---

The example you reference ([`hudson.plugins.clearcase.ItemListenerImpl`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ItemListenerImpl.java)) is a particular case of [Hudson `ItemListener`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/listeners/ItemListener.html).